# Django: Global modification of readonly field appearance

Tags: python, django, python-import

I want to customize the field texture in django’s new “[readonly mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission)”: E.g. foreign keys shall be displayed as links.

In general I identified the following options:

- Implement custom fields for every model – results in code duplication
- Reimplement django’s display_for_field method

Basically I could copy & paste the django.contrib.admin.utils module, insert my changes, override `sys.modules['django.contrib.admin.utils'] = myutils` but that's ugly because of maintainability in case of Django updates in the future.

So I decided to override only the display_for_fields method of `django.contrib.admin.utils` using the following approach to avoid duplication of Django code:

1. Override display_for_field function in django.contrib.admin.utils in settings.py:

   ```
   from myapp.contrib.admin import utils
   utils.override_method()
   ```
2. In myapp.utils.py:

   ```
   from django.contrib.admin import utils
   from django.contrib.admin.utils import *


   def display_for_field_mod(value, field, empty_value_display):
       if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey) and value:
           if field.related_model.__name__.lower() != 'user':
               link_string = 'admin:myapp_' + field.related_model.__name__.lower() + '_change'
               link = reverse(link_string, args=(value.id,))
               return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', link, value)
           else:
               return formats.localize(value)
       else:
           return display_for_field(value, field, empty_value_display)


   def override_method():
       utils.display_for_field = display_for_field_mod
   ```

But the problem is: display_for_field gets imported in django.contrib.admin.helpers using:

```
    from django.contrib.admin.utils import (
        display_for_field, [...]
    )
```

So due to the scope of the imported funtion I cannot override this function from outside.

Do I miss some other obvious possibility? Is there a clean method to achieve this or is the only option to duplicate/modify django’s original code?

Comment: Can't you create your custom `ModelAdmin` base class that overrides `formfield_for_foreignkey()` and then make all your model admins subclass that base class?

Comment: That’s the example they give, but it actually returns the form field.

Comment: If the user has only view permissions, all fields get marked as readonly fields, thus the modification in formfield_for_foreignkey doesn' work as setting a modified widget for a foreignkey field will have no effect and instead the display_for_field function is called. So apparently i would have to remove the fields from readonly_fields again... The question is: at which point this would make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue. If anyone's still looking for a solution, you just need to override the `display_for_field` in `helpers`, e.g.:

```py
from django.contrib.admin import helpers, utils

def override_method():
    helpers.display_for_field = display_for_field_mod
    utils.display_for_field = display_for_field_mod
```

Only overriding `helpers` is sufficient, but it's a good idea to override `utils` as well, just in case.

Comment: Actually this was the solution I picked finally. But I needed some additional patch to handle many to many fields...